# can I pass a hash to an instance method to create instance variables?

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, instance-variables

I have a has like this:

```
reminder_hash = {"bot_client_id"=>"test-client-id", "recurring"=>true, "recurring_natural_language"=>"everyday", "time_string"=>"10AM", "time_zone"=>"America/Los_Angeles", "via"=>"slack", "keyword"=>"test-keyword", "status"=>"active", "created_time"=>1444366166000}
```

I would like to pass to method like this (from Rspec):

```
let(:reminder) { Reminder.new( reminder_hash ) }
```

I would like the instance variables for Reminder to be based on the hash.

```
expect(reminder.bot_client_id).to eq('test-client-id')
```

I can't get it to work.  I tried the following:

class Reminder

attr_accessor :bot_client_id

```
def initiate(hash)
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615190/declaring-instance-variables-iterating-over-a-hash

    hash.each do |k,v|

      instance_variable_set("@#{k}",v)
      # if you want accessors:

      eigenclass = class<<self; self; end

      eigenclass.class_eval do

        attr_accessor k
      end

    end

  end
```

Rspec gives the following error:

```
Failure/Error: let(:reminder) { Reminder.new( reminder_hash ) }
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

**Question:** How do I pass a hash to an instance method for an object, so that the hash values are the instance variables for that newly created object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do something like this in your initialize method:

```
     hash.each do |k, v|
        instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
        self.class.send(:attr_reader, k)
      end
```

Here's an example using your input hash:

```
class Reminder
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each do |k, v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
      self.class.send(:attr_reader, k)
    end
  end
end


reminder_hash = {"bot_client_id"=>"test-client-id", "recurring"=>true, "recurring_natural_language"=>"everyday", "time_string"=>"10AM", "time_zone"=>"America/Los_Angeles", "via"=>"slack", "keyword"=>"test-keyword", "status"=>"active", "created_time"=>1444366166000}

reminder = Reminder.new(reminder_hash)
puts reminder

puts reminder.bot_client_id
```

Output:

```
#<Reminder:0x007f8a48831498>
test-client-id
```

Comment: I see. Why was my version getting a wrong arguments error!

Comment: This looks great. Gonna try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) to do that.

```
require 'ostruct'

reminder_hash = {"bot_client_id"=>"test-client-id", "recurring"=>true, "recurring_natural_language"=>"everyday", "time_string"=>"10AM", "time_zone"=>"America/Los_Angeles", "via"=>"slack", "keyword"=>"test-keyword", "status"=>"active", "created_time"=>1444366166000}
reminder = OpenStruct.new(reminder_hash)

p reminder.bot_client_id # => "test-client-id"
```

Use a Struct for a full blown Class:

```
Reminder = Struct.new(*reminder_hash.keys.map(&:to_sym))
r = Reminder.new(*reminder_hash.values)

p r.bot_client_id # => "test-client-id"
```

Comment: @Angela not with Openstruct, but with a Struct - see edited answer.

Comment: I guess if I were to do r.class it would give me => Reminder?  which is what I think I am looking for....

Comment: how is it different from the way above?  the other answer?